# Python string is out of index

Tags: python, string, indexing

I'm trying to delete 'X' and the char before X and here is my code

```
s = input()
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == 'X':
        s = s.replace("X", "")
        s = s.replace(s[i], "")
```

i got out of index error

```
    if s[i] == 'X':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

What's the problem here and how to fix it?

Comment: Instead of deleting characters from a string you are iterating over, create a new string without those characters.

Comment: So what's the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yes i can remove all X in one shot, but who i delete the char before each X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
s = "aXbcXd" #example string
s = re.sub(".?X", "", s)
print(s)
#output: bd
```

Comment: Thank you this works well! but i have a question, is ".?" means the char before X??

Comment: '.' in regex means any character and and '?' means that the character is optional (if X were at start of the string)

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
f= []
x = input()
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    if x[i+1]=='X' or x[i]=='X':
        continue
    else:
        f.append(x[i])

final = ''.join(f)
```

Comment: yes it works but if there is more than one X doesn't work!

Comment: Plz check the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
s = input()
ls = len(s)
x_pos = []
for i in range(ls):
    if s[i] == 'X':
        if i != 0:
            x_pos.append(i - 1)
            x_pos.append(i)
        else:
            x_pos.append(i)
new_s = ''
for j in range(ls):
    if j not in x_pos:
        new_s += s[j]

print(new_s)
```

Comment: It works thank you! but i think it's slower than the other solutions, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, best way to address this problem would be using regular expressions. An alternative method could be this.
 
Solution:

```
s = input()
def removeX(s):
    pos = s.find('X')
    if pos == -1:
        print(s)
        return
    elif pos == 0:
        s = s[pos+1:]
    else:
        s = s[:pos-1]+s[pos+1:]
    removeX(s)

removeX(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use while loop

```
s = input()
while True:
    a = s.find('X')
    if a==-1:
        break
    if a==0:
        s = s[1:]
    else:
        s = s[:a-1]+s[a+1:]
```